# Div - border until is text

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div id="test">
    DYNAMIC DATA FROM PHP <br />
DYNAMIC DATA FROM PHP
DYNAMIC DATA FROM PHP
</div>

<div id="test2">
    DYNAMIC DATA FROM PHP <br />
DYNAMIC DATA FROM PHP
DYNAMIC DATA FROM PHP
</div>

#test {
   border: solid 1px red;


   width: auto;
}

#test2 {
   border: solid 1px green;


   width: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jcgtL/15/

How can i make border for current area? In this example div extends to right AREA BROWSER.
i can't use for example width: 100px or less, because this data i generated with PHP.
Maybe i mus use jQuery?

EDIT:

this is not inline element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use `float: left` in these situations ( or `right` if it fits ).

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/jcgtL/10/

Answer (score 3):

You're using a `div` element which is a block element, you should use a `span` which is an inline element.

Comment: +1 a span is the right idea. You could also change your style to `display: inline;` but a span is already inline, so won't cause any nesting problems either.

Comment: i can't use span - this is not inline element.

Answer (score 1):

add a `position:fixed` into your style and it should look how you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/jcgtL/1/

Comment: You totally want to go with the other suggestions of using the right element... in this case looks like you want a `span`

Answer (score 1):

try this please may be it will help you. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jcgtL/27/)

Answer (score 0):

I inserted a span http://jsfiddle.net/jcgtL/4/

Comment: sorry, i can't use span, this is not inline